# ruby catch classes as they are defined

Tags: ruby, libgosu

Building tile games or simulations in Ruby Gosu always makes me end upp with a list of all available tiles, saved by their class. For example `[Pipe, PipeJunktion, Box, Pump]` and so on. Each class is defined in one of a few separate files, which i required from the main program. For now i have to add the class myself to this list every time I add a new tile to the game. I was wondering if there was a way to catch all loading classes from a file.

Something along the lines of:

```
allTiles = []
require_relative 'tiles.rb'.each_class {|class| allTiles << class}
```

would be handy.
Or can this be solved with modules in some way?

Comment: Do you need them to be in an array? You could also just load them all and iterate over the descendants of the superclass..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking which classes were added by a file is not something that's easily or commonly done. A better approach would be to put all the tile classes under a single namespace. Since classes can be re-opened, these can be split among multiple files.

```
class Tiles
  class Pipe
    # ...
  end
end

class Tiles
  class Box
    # ...
  end
end
```

Then `Tiles.constants` could would return an array of symbols: `[:Pipe, :Box]`, and could be used to get a list of class references using `Tiles.constants.map { |const| Tiles.const_get const }` or `Tiles.constants.map &Tiles.method(:const_get)`

If for whatever reason it was really important to know which constants were added by a specific file, the following code shows an approach:

```
constants1 = Object.constants
require "./tiles.rb"
constants2 = Object.constants
added_constants = constants2 - constants1
```

If `tiles.rb` had class definitions for `Pipe` and `Box`, then `added_constants` would be `[:Pipe, :Box]`.

The problem with this approach is that might show constants added by gems, for example:

```
constants1 = Object.constants
require 'mechanize'
class Foo
end
constants2 = Object.constants
added_constants = constants2 - constants1
```

Since I called `require 'mechanize'`, the `added_constants` list will be quite long and include much more than just `Foo`.

Comment: Ah this is perfect, didn't know you could use classes as namespaces like that. You learn something everyday with this language!

Comment: Yeah, read up on namespacing in ruby because theres more than this

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
Dir['tiles/*.rb'].each { |file| require file }
```

What would collect all files from a `tiles` subfolder and requires it.

In a next step load all classes by their file names:

```
all_tiles = Dir['tiles/*.rb'].map do |file| 
  file_name = File.basename(x, '.*')
  camel_cased_name = file_name.split('_').collect(&:capitalize).join
  Object.const_get(camel_cased_name)
end
```

Btw the same can be done in Rails like this:

```
all_tiles = Dir['tiles/*.rb'].map do |file| 
  File.basename(x, '.*').camelize.constantize
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there are pitfalls with the following approach, but I will put it out and invite comments.

First, use [ObjectSpace::each_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/ObjectSpace.html#method-c-each_object) to compile a list of all classes that exist before any custom classes have been created:

```
base_classes = ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a
```

For my version of Ruby (2.4.0), within IRB, `base_classes.size #=> 490`. Now load the code with `require`'s etc. Suppose that causes three classes to be created:

```
class A; end
class B; end
class C; end
```

Now compile a list of all classes that now exist and subtract `base_classes`:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object(Class).to_a - base_classes
  #=> [A, B, C]
```

This returns an array of classes that have been added by my code.

Of course this does not show classes in `base_classes` that are overridden by my code or show which classes are defined by required gems.